# Poisson Modeled Probability of Success

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

So a sensor doesn't get active if it receives less than 4 photons per ms.if the number of photons received is modeled after the poisson probability law what is the probability of the sensor getting active when you put it in front of a light source that emits 10k photons /S.

What I don't understand is how i use the poisson law here, taking in that average is 10 whats the x that i apply in the formula?0.4 or 1 for just one success?

Comment: It seems you are not told how long you put it in front of the light source.  If you put it there and wait long enough, eventually it will become active (with prob 1) because a 4-ms interval will eventually arise in which there are at least 4 arriving photons.